# Stackoverflow Exception Entity Framework 3.1.3 when Seeding Large Dataset

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When running the `update-database` command to my `mssql` server to seed a large dataset parsed from a CSV I am getting a `stack overflow` exception.

I seed the data from a number of legacy CSV files in `OnModelCreating`.

It is a large data set and contains around 9.5k lines of input which is split across a number of POCOs.

`-verbose` gives no further information on the issue other than it is trying to apply the migration.

I am using `Visual Studio 2019 Community` and `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.3`.

Can I safely comment out some of the seeding (i.e. seed 50%) in the `up()` method of the migration?

How would I then seed the remaining data safely? (would EF on the OnModelBuilding method check the data on the next `add-migration` and generate the missing data? or would it assume it was seeded after checking the migrations table?

Comment: You could apply the migration at runtime to debug. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I get the same stack overflow by running the migration at run time too?

Comment: What's the stack look like?

Comment: And add the stack trace and enough code to enable a repro to your question.

Comment: No problem, I have created a project here stripping everything out. https://github.com/mfitconsultants/EntityFrameworkCoreStackOverflowException I'm not sure how to get a stack trace at this point though if you could advise on how I can get this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `initialcreate.Up(MigrationBuilder)` method is too big and is blowing up the JITter.  The StackOverflow is occuring when the MSIL for the method is compiled to machine language code.

This is because there's just too much code of the form

```
  migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Addresses",
        columns: new[] { "Id", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Country", "DateCreated", "IsArchived", "IsPrimaryAddress", "LastModifiedDate", "LastModifiedUser", "NickName", "Notes", "PostCode", "Region", "Town" },
        values: new object[,]
        {
            { 1, "669A George Street", null, null, "", new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 108, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1514), null, true, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 108, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1545), null, null, null, "AB25 3XP", "", "Aberdeen" },
            { 12307, "7 Moredon Road", null, null, "", new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8799), null, true, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8800), null, null, null, "SN25 3DQ ", "", "Swindon" },
            { 12306, "", null, null, null, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8735), null, false, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8736), null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { 12305, "67 HIGH STREET, ", null, null, "", new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8690), null, true, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8690), null, null, null, "TQ95 5NU", "", "TOTNES" },
            { 12304, "", null, null, null, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8577), null, false, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8579), null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { 12303, "BOWS KITCHEN, 10 MARGATE PLACE,", null, null, "", new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8530), null, true, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8531), null, null, null, "CT9 1EN", "", "MARGATE" },
            { 12302, "", null, null, null, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8464), null, false, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8465), null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { 12308, "", null, null, null, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8849), null, false, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8850), null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { 12301, "270 ST SAVIOURS RD", null, null, "", new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8417), null, true, new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 14, 58, 51, 198, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(8418), null, null, null, "LE5 4HF", "", "LEICESTER" },
```

in the method.  To resolve this, the best method would be to read the data for each InserData from disk before each call.  Or to embed the data in your source code as, say JSON strings and convert it to an `object[,]` at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to look at this. Could you expand a bit on what you mean by read the data from disk before each call? Do you mean I'd manually alter the up() method?

Comment: Yes, Move the code you have in OnModelCreating into the migration, so you don't emit a Migration class with so many lines of code. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#manual-migration-customization